# Bash : How to store STDOUT (&1) pointer in a variable

Tags: bash, stdout, io-redirection

Here is a simple (and maybe dummy) question in an as-simple-as-the-question scenario.

I want to store my output file in a variable :

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/myown/backup.log
```

So I can build my script this way:

```
#!/bin/bash
LOG=/var/log/myown/backup.log
echo "Backup créé le $(date)" >>$LOG
```

Also, I'd like to make this possible for the LOG variable to point to **STDOUT**.

Then I could simply change the value of `LOG` as in `LOG=&1` so it does not writeout to a file but to **STDOUT**.

Comment: You can't use `&1`, but with modern versions of bash you can use `1` (the `&` needs to be syntax rather than data).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this what you need?

```
LOG=/dev/stdout
```

Or perhaps:

```
LOG=/var/log/myown/backup.log
exec 4> "$LOG"  ## exec >>4 "$LOG" to append
echo "Backup créé le $(date)" >&4
```

Or finally:

```
LOG=/var/log/myown/backup.log
exec 4> "$LOG"  ## exec >>4 "$LOG" to append
LOG_FD=4  ## Change to 1 to put back to stdout.
echo "Backup créé le $(date)" >&"$LOG_FD"
```

You can also use a function for convenience:

```
function log {
    echo "$1" >&"$LOG_FD"
}
log "Backup créé le $(date)"
```

Comment: Probable worth noting that the 2nd usage (`>&"$LOG_FD"`) is only available with modern releases.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I think you're referring to `exec {LOG_FD}>log.txt`.

Comment: Hmm. I was under the distinct impression that there was another syntax extension that went in at the same time, to make dynamically-assigned FDs actually usable in redirections. Might need to go back and look at exactly what it was.

Answer (score 1):

In modern (4.1+) versions of bash, you can use expansions to refer to file descriptors:

```
log_fd=1                # hardcode FD 1 as output source
echo "Hello" >&$log_fd  # ...and use that value
```

This is extra handy with automatic file descriptor allocation, also added in 4.1:

```
exec {log_fd}>log.txt   # open log.txt on an automatically-assigned free FD
                        # ...and save that FD number in log_fd
echo "Hello" >&$log_fd  # write to log.txt on that FD
```

You can't put the `&` itself into the variable -- which is actually better design; otherwise, you couldn't redirect to a filename starting with a literal `&`, and any program wherein a user could specify a filename would allow the user to target stdout/stderr/etc -- but that's no loss of flexibility, since you can open any filename on any FD using `exec` in its redirection-enacting usage mode.

Comment: *In modern (4.1+) versions of bash, you can use expansions to refer to file descriptors* should be corrected. That works even at least since 2.05.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want [`tee`](http://man.cx/tee)

```
LOG=/var/log/myown/backup.log
echo "Backup créé le $(date)" | tee -a $LOG
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, much appreciated but when redirected to a file, I don't necessarily want it to print out to STDOUT...